# React Native: running 'npm audit fix' updates RN0.67 to RN0.69 and leads to complette App rendering fail

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

So today i ran 'npm audit fix' after installing a new package showed me 6 critical vulnurabilities.
I can't remember when i did this the last time, but definitly after my RN version 0.67 wasn't the newest version anymore.
I've gone up and down trying to figure out why my projects wouldnt compile anymore, but i think I've come to the core issue.

Both my projects run fine on RN0.67

I run 'npm audit fix' and RN gets updated to 0.69

I add a bit of code into my android/app/build.gradle, since these two dependencies now require
compileSdkVersion = 31:

```
android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {

    configurations.all {
      resolutionStrategy { 
        force 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
        force 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.3.1'  
     }
  }
```

I clear my App.js of all imported dependencies and screens, just to be sure

The App builds successfully, but the debugAPK either fails installing, crashes instantly, or showes a white screen with this error log each time i touch the screen:

```
  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ReactCurrentActQueue$1.isBatchingLegacy')
```

[TypeError each time the screen gets touched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZmFu.png)

I could find anything about this error online, apart from an unsolved simular problem in React.

Please let me know if i should provide any additional info.

Should i just ignore the critical warnings for now, or try a complettely new RN0.69 project and figure something out?

Comment: same issue, please help!

Comment: same here, cant find a solution

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue for the past two weeks and today it's working !

I have done two upgrades:

Upgrade npm 8.11.0 -> 8.13.2 with `sudo npm install -g npm@8.13.2`
and Upgrade react-native v0.69.0 -> v0.69.1 with `npx react-native upgrade`.

I'm a beginner so I have no idea what the source of this problem is or why this solution works.

I hope this can help!

Comment: I hoped the Update would be a Hotfix to whatever was happening, but after upgrading both my App now instantly crashes without log, i might try with a blank project, to see if some added dependency causes this